# Display only 3 items using CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, owl-carousel

I am using `owl.carousel.min.js` JavaScript. I have to display only 3 images on my screen. For that I have written an extra JavaScript:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        item:3,
        slideBy: 4,

        singleItem: true
    });
  });
 </script>
```

But it didn't work. Where will I have do changes in my `owl.carousel.min.js`?

Comment: Have you respected library include order jQuery -> owl.carousel -> script?

Comment: Add your errors in your question and also add your other code that handles the images as well.

Comment: feed it 3 items & it will have 3 items only.

Comment: Thank for your appreciation.But  I solved it